# How do you print multiple inputs from one variable?

Tags: c

We have an exercise that requires us to verify the inputs using a do-while loop. We are only allowed to use inputs from the variable, no other variables are allowed. The program is to reprint the inputs after the do-while loop.

I am stuck at the do-while verification and have no idea how to take the other inputs and reprint them in another line other than the last input.

```
int p, score, i = 1;
    
printf("Enter the number of players: ");
scanf("%d", &gs);
    
do{
  printf("Enter score of player #%d: ", i);
  scanf("%d", &score);
  i++;
        
} while(i <= gs);

printf("Score of player #%d: %d", i, score);
```

Expected Output:

```
Score of player #1: 34
.
.
.
Score of player #n: n
```

Comment: If you can print them immediately after inputting them, before inputting the next value, then that would work.  But if you need to print them all together, after the last input has been read, then you'll need to store them.  In that case you can use an array.

Comment: Edited it already. The program is supposed to reprint all the inputs from the do-while loop.

Comment: Please add a simple example of input and and expected output. This would be much clearer than a description. From what I've understood you need an array.

Comment: It seems we are getting your interpretation of what the requirements are and they seem to make little sense. Can you quote the literal instructions you have received? (or as close to those as possible) Or some kind of context, you could do this with an array or (maybe) with recursion, was any of that mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You can't do that without storing the scores in an array. You probably misunderstood something in the wording of the original requirement. Or maybe it could work with recursion. You need to tell us more.

Comment: The instructions were "create a program that will verify inputs of the number of players with their scores in a game. Find a way to reprint them. Use a do while-loop to verify the inputs." We were also instructed to not use arrays.

Comment: Honestly I am also very confused with the instructions and I tried asking our professor about it and just said the instructions were clear for him.

Comment: You could maybe use recursion, but that rules out the do/while loop. Also the wording _Use a do while-loop to verify the inputs_ sounds odd, how could a do/while loop be used to _verify_ the inputs? It's a shame that there are so many teachers that give bull shit exercises like this one instead of properly teaching programming. If you find out yourself, please post the answer here, I'd be curious.

Comment: We could find several ways to abuse the requirements (e.g. store to a file with open/read/write?) but it's not obvious what you were *supposed* to do.

Comment: I'll do my best to search for one. I may still be a newbie but I know this is also confusing as hell for those who practice a lot.

Comment: “Find a way to reprint them”. To me that doesn’t sound like you have to print them after you’re done reading them. Perhaps you can just print them as you go?

Comment: @SafelyFast apparently that's not what he wants, look at the expected output at the end of the question.

Comment: What exactly is meant by "verify the inputs"?  Is there a range of valid values?  If so, that's what the loop is for: to keep reading values until you get a valid one.  Then that loop is inside of another loop that iterates for each player.

Answer (score 1):

May be can use pointer.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
int main()
{
    int i = 0, gs = 0;
    int* scope = NULL;

    printf("Enter the number of players: ");
    scanf("%d", &gs);
    scope = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * gs);
    if (scope == NULL)
    {
        printf("No space\n");
        return 1;
    }
    do
    {
        printf("Enter score of player %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &scope[i]);
        i++;

    } while (i < gs);

    for (i = 0; i < gs; i++)
    {
        printf("Score of player #%d: %d\n", i + 1, scope[i] );
    }
    free(scope);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is picture:

[image]